# The meanings of the notations $L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ and $C^1(-\pi,\pi)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm reading through a proof on the existence of the Gibbs phenomenon for a general function $f(x)$ with a jump discontinuity at $x=0$, and ran into the notations in the title. What are their meanings, and what would it mean if the $1$s were changed into $n$s as follows
$$
L^n(-\pi,\pi) \quad \text{and}\quad C^n(-\pi,\pi),
$$
since I'm guessing this is possible and also means something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C^n(a,b)$ means functions $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ which are $n$ times continuously differentiable (i.e. if one takes the derivative $n$ times, the result is still a continuous function). When $n=\infty$, we say that the functions in $C^{\infty}(a,b)$ are smooth.

$L^n(a,b)$ means functions $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^b|f(x)|^n dx$ exists (and is finite). Here, $n$ can be any value in $(0,\infty]$, with the caveat that if $n=\infty$, we want $\inf\{C\geq 0:|f(x)|\leq C\text{ a.e. } x\in(a,b)\}$ to be finite, rather than an integrality condition. (Here a.e. means '[almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).')

Comment: shouldn't we had the equivalence relation:
 $f \sim g$ iff $g=f$ almost everywhere, 
in order to fully define the space?

Comment: @chak Yes, thank you, that is a good point. I am assuming that the OP may not know the definition of "almost everywhere" if they do not yet know the above common notations. In any case, every function in each of these spaces is equivalent to a function that I have mentioned.

Comment: TheSodesa, what @chak and Ben S talk about is that the $L^n$ spaces actually contain equivalence classes of functions. That's however nothing that one normally has to worry about.

Comment: Wikipedia article on $L^p$ spaces (the variable $p$ is normally used instead of $n$): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: You should stress that for $L^n(a,b)$, the number $n$ can be anything in $[0,\infty]$ with the case $n=\infty$ defined separately.

Comment: $L^p$ can mean a space of actual functions. It doesn't always mean a set of equivalence classes

Comment: @edm Thank you for the suggestion; I have included it.